# Why am I approving Tag Edits for higher rep users?

Tags: support

I just went through approving tag edits for Timmy Jim, a user outclassing my rep by 10K+. Is this normal function for the website? I've just never encountered it before, though I only did recently receive the ability to approve/deny tag edits.

Comment: Note you aren't the only reviewer either, you need at least two people to review a suggested edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Timmy Jim, despite his impressive rep score (currently around 15k), does not have enough to earn the [Trusted User](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) permission, which requires 20k rep. As explained on the linked help page:

> Trusted users are allowed to perform trusted actions, including:
>
> - Voting to delete answers with score of -1 or lower
> - Voting to undelete answers except those deleted by a moderator
> - Voting to delete questions with a score of -3 or lower immediately after they are closed
> - **Editing tag wikis without needing approval**

I would imagine the system is set up this way so that tags need to be "peer reviewed" for most users, especially since tags are ubiquitous and used all around the site for questions of any type. Only once a user has very strongly proven that they know how the site works can they edit tag wikis directly without approval.

Comment: [semi-related, but mostly to highlight the significance of this site privilege](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12163/could-tag-wiki-reviewers-please-check-for-plagiarism).

Comment: Thanks Mage, Vemenous, and Robotnik for clearing this up!